# how I can install android os from pc to my phone

Tags: android, installation

I want way to install android OS from my pc to my phone by USB manually , when my OS is destroy
please any one help me
thanks

Comment: This is off-topic question. Ask it in another [stack exchange site](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download **custom rom** from internet and install that custom rom to your android phone using USB cable

[Check this link](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-custom-rom-android/)